# How to override 'vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/product_types.xml' in Magento 2.1?

Tags: overrides, magento-2.1, product-types.xml

In Magento 2.0 if you put the file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/product_types.xml` inside your module's etc folder, it'll be overridden. But this same behaviour is not working in `Magento 2.1`. So basically I want to override this `vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/product_types.xml` in Magento 2.1.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

EDIT:
The content of `app/code/Mynamespace/Mymodule/etc/product_types.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <composableTypes>
        <type name="configurable" />
    </composableTypes>
</config>
```

Comment: Have you checked using deploy and remove var folder same as magento 2.0 way?

Comment: Yes, It doesn't give any error. Instead can't login to admin panel. But the frontend is working

Comment: Please post the content of your overriden file

Comment: @ Raphael at Digital Pianism : Updated the question

Comment: What you want specifically want ? You want your custom product type?

Comment: This file sets the associated product types for grouped products. I want to add configurable product also as an associate product type for grouped products

Comment: any success  yet?

Comment: @Pallavi : Let me check and get back to you. I was forgotten this question.